# How to solve AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute '_variables' for PyTest on Jenkins Execution

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, pytest, attributeerror

Trying to execute PyTest automation scripts using Jenkins Jobs. Initially I had configured 2 Jenkins Jobs with the exact same configuration. Scripts are running successfully with both jobs. Later I had created a 3rd job with the exact same configuration; but for same scripts/configuration it is throwing attribute error. Please find error details below,

```
"Executing tests"
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 265, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     config._do_configure()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 1056, in _do_configure
INTERNALERROR>     self.hook.pytest_configure.call_historic(kwargs=dict(config=self))
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 277, in call_historic
INTERNALERROR>     res = self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, False)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Integration-Automation\sf_venv\lib\site-packages\pytest_selenium\pytest_selenium.py", line 249, in pytest_configure
INTERNALERROR>     capabilities = config._variables.get("capabilities", {})
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute '_variables'
"Test complete."
```

Batch batch command I am using -

```
pip install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv test
call .\test\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install -r requirements.txt
echo "Executing tests"
python -m pytest ./src/scripts/activities -v -m mytags --environment="TestEnvironment" --stream="TestStream" --junitxml="test_results/results.xml"
call deactivate
echo "Test complete."
```

Tried to execute scripts with differenet configuration like changing batch commands or not running both jobs in series.

Comment: I'm making an automatic question editing tool. Do you mind if I add this question to a dataset?

Comment: There are some files missing from your question. What's the smallest version of these files that continues to have this issue?

Comment: As I mentioned in question,  scripts are executed successfully with the exact same configuration but on the older Jenkins job. I have created new job by cloning existing job for which I am getting AttributeError.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - You can add this question to your dataset, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but if you can provide a complete example that's causing this problem, other people can try to reproduce your setup, and narrow down the possible causes. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and while I haven't figured out what exactly is causing it, I'm pretty confident it is a result of upgrading to pytest 7. The same test works fine with pytest 6.2.5 and fails in 7.2.2. 
Update: It's actually pytest-variables 3.0.0:

`Use pytest.stash internally instead of _variables`

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-variables/blob/master/CHANGES.rst

Comment: Thanks @steffen; the issue is  PyTest version only. Working as expected now.